# C# Web Forms - Perdendo sessão

Tags: c#, webforms, session, iis, timeout

Tenho uma aplicação em Web Forms que guarda a sessão quando o usuário loga, com um tempo limite de 21 minutos sem utilizar a aplicação para expirar a sessão:

```
<sessionState timeout="21" />
```

Realizando testes na máquina local, o limite funciona perfeitamente, porém temos vários clientes utilizando em produção, com uma publicação para cada cliente utilizando as mesmas configurações no IIS, inclusive configurado os mesmos 21 minutos.
O que está ocorrendo é que em alguns clientes a sessão está expirando antes do tempo configurado.
Verificando o código, não encontrei nada que poderia estar implicando nisso, pois o `Session.Abandon()`, está sendo chamado apenas no logout da aplicação, como deve ser realmente.
Gostaria de saber se alguém já passou por isso, e se conseguiu resolver o problema?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o problema seja na configuração do IIS. Provavelmente nele a configuração de timeout esteja com um tempo menor.

Comment: Eduardo agradeço sua resposta, porém o IIS está configurado com os mesmos 21 minutos do config.

Comment: Vc está em algum WebFarm ou em algum serviço de PAAS?

Comment: Não utilizamos WebFarm nem PAAS.

Answer (score 0):

Podem ser vários os motivos para a sessão estar sendo perdida. Geralmente está vinculado ao Pool de Aplicativos ou o próprio IIS serem reiniciados. Isso pode ocorrer por algum dos seguintes motivos:

- Quando o arquivo Web.Config é editado.
- Quando algum novo componente do IIS é instalado.
- Quando o tempo de Reciclagem do Pool de Aplicativos for atingido (configurado no IIS).
- Quando uma exceção não tratada for disparada na aplicação.